# JavaFx - When does StringConverter.fromString execute in DatePicker

Tags: javafx

I am trying to customize a DatePicker and would like to add a red border to the TextField/Editor of the DatePicker while the user input is invalid and remove it again as soon as it becomes valid. The only problem I have with this is triggering the validation, I can't seem to get the fromString method in the converter to execute (which then updates a property and so on ..., this is all fine).

I was under the impression the fromString method would execute on user input, but apparently it does not, so my question basically comes down to "when does the fromString method execute".

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't matter when `DatePicker` uses the converter, but when you want the conversion to be checked. You could simply do this with a listener to the `text` property of the `editor`.

The binding in the following code registers such a listener:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
    TextField editor = datePicker.getEditor();
    StringConverter<LocalDate> converter = datePicker.getConverter();
    editor.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> {
        try {
            converter.fromString(editor.getText());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "-fx-background-color: red;";
        }
        return null;
    }, editor.textProperty()));

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(datePicker), 200, 100);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

---

**Edit:** the converter is used when the text is input is "commited" using <kbd>Enter</kbd> while focusing the `editor`.

Comment: I know, but I kinda expected the fromString method to be triggered just like the toString method is triggered and therefor I am a bit confused that I apparently have to trigger it "by hand"

Comment: I mean, thanks for your answer, but my question is not "how do I get the red border on faulty input" my question is "why does the fromString-method not trigger as I expect"

Comment: Do you by "submitted" mean "commited", as in `commitValue()`? Because `commitValue()` only triggers the `toString()` method

Comment: If you want to know exactly where it's called: `ComboBoxPopupControl.handleKeyEvent` and it only triggers on perssing the enter key... no other code seems to be using the converter.